# Full outer join with linq for 3 tables

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have 3 entities in EntityModel: Customer, CustomerAddress (this is junction entity with Ids and orderOnControl columns and cant be ommited in model) and Address. I need to make linq query to FULL JOIN Customer with Address. This query in SQL is plain:

```
select e1.[AddressID], e1.City, e3.CustomerID, e3.LastName from [SalesLT].[Address] as e1
full join [SalesLT].[CustomerAddress] as e2 on e1.[AddressID] = e2.[AddressID]
full join [SalesLT].[Customer] as e3 on e2.CustomerID = e3.CustomerID
```

but I need to write this with linq, I found answers where there are 2 entities with many-to-may relation, but couldn't find any with junction entity, I would appreciate any tips

Comment: `FULL JOIN` ? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, I need full join (result will serve as datasource for control where I could check checkbox to join row elements). I think "LINQ - Full Outer Join" is different scenerio with two tables.

Comment: You can apply the two table solution twice to get a 3 table full outer join.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. This LINQ statement will join Customers to Addresses through the junction table CustomerAddress.

```
var query = from ca in context.CustomerAddress
    join a in context.Address on ca.AddressId equals a.AddressId
    join c in context.Customer on ca.CustomerId equals c.CustomerId
    select new { a.AddressId, a.City, c.CustomerId, c.LastName };
```

Comment: It joins elements which have join condition, I need to list all rows from right and left table. Maybe I will just concat elements that doesn't have id in junction table to result of your query...

Comment: It will join but it will give us the result of inner join not full join